# How to close the panel after clicking the Google Classroom icon in the application

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-classroom

I have integrated google-classroom in my application using its render method as    `gapi.sharetoclassroom.render("googleClassroomBtn",{
                            "size": "34",
                            "theme" : "dark",
                            "url": googleClassroomURL,
                            "title": titleText 
                        });`

What i required is to close my share panel once the user has clicked on it, due to Google library integrated, i am unable to access the click on it.

Is there any way possible or any event which will be received once user click on the google-classroom icon or any way i can send a callback function to it.

Comment: Have you tried using the [window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) command? This is usually the method use to close current tabs or windows opened.

Comment: window.close() will close the window but i just need to close the panel in which i have placed the share button, i am not getting that click when user has clicked on to share.